# why I got two temporary objects when returning a object from a function

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

This is my c++ code

```
class CTest {
public:
    int number;
    int arr[10];
};

CTest Return(int val) {
    CTest obj;
    obj.number = val;
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    CTest obj = Return(10);
    return 0;
}
```

I found that there are two temporary objects by the looking at assembly code

```
//in main

    CTest obj = Return(10);
0009F6CE  push        0Ah  
0009F6D0  lea         eax,[ebp-158h]  ; pass the first temporary object's address to Return
0009F6D6  push        eax  
0009F6D7  call        Return (0822E9h)  
0009F6DC  add         esp,8  
0009F6DF  mov         ecx,0Bh  
0009F6E4  mov         esi,eax  
0009F6E6  lea         edi,[ebp-124h]  ; copy from the first temporary object
0009F6EC  rep movs    dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr [esi]  
0009F6EE  mov         ecx,0Bh  
0009F6F3  lea         esi,[ebp-124h]  
0009F6F9  lea         edi,[obj]       ; copy from the second temporary object
0009F6FC  rep movs    dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr [esi]

//in Return

    CTest obj;
    obj.number = val;
0009F64E  mov         eax,dword ptr [val]  
0009F651  mov         dword ptr [obj],eax  
    return obj;
0009F654  mov         ecx,0Bh  
0009F659  lea         esi,[obj]  
0009F65C  mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
0009F65F  rep movs    dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr [esi]  ; copy to the first temporary object
0009F661  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]
```

Why I got the second temporary object. Seems only one temporary object is enough. If I add an empty destructor `~CTest() {}` will not have a temporary object (RVO?).

Comment: It's the return and the assignment (copying). Your compiler apparently didn't perform copy elision.

Comment: Did you compile the code with optimizations?

Comment: With optimizations my compiler compiles main to: `xor eax, eax; ret`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, I am learning assembly in debug mode with no optimizations. The first temporary is for returning and the second temporary is for assigning, right?

Comment: Which compiler is this? Is it msvc?

Answer (score 0):

> "Why I got the second temporary object"

It is probably because you turned off the optimization.

Otherwise, the compiler will make an optimization by passing `obj` from the main as a hidden parameter (just like `this` pointer) to the Return function and will assign the "result" to it.

So after optimization your code will look like this:

```
void Return(void* put_result_here , int val) {
    CTest obj;
    obj.number = val;
    put_result_here = obj;
}


int main() {
    CTest obj; 
    Return(&obj , 10);
    return 0;
}
```

This optimization called **return by value optimization**.

Comment: The transformation isn't going to replace construction with assignment. The code will look more like: `(void*) put_result_here` and `{ obj = *(new (put_result_here) CTest); obj.number = val; }` but there would be no construction of `obj` in `main`. Trying to do pseudo-code for this is (IMHO) very misleading.